# jQuery - hide all elements except first one

Tags: jquery, loops, each

Let's say I have 10 buttons. I want to hide all the buttons except the first one.

Im trying to accomplish it using each() in jQuery but its not working.

Here's my script. This is only a test to see if I can get the index of the buttons. There are no errors appearing.

```
$('button').each(function(index){
    alert(index);
});
```

Additional Info:

My whole script is this

```
$(function(){
   $('div#here').load('test.php'); // This is where all the buttons will come from
   $('button').each(function(index){
       alert(index);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as ThiefMaster but don't forget that you need to wait for buttons to be load.

You need to use the callback of load :

```
$(function(){
$('div#here').load('test.php', function(){
   $('button:not(:first)').hide();
}); // This is where all the buttons will come from

});
```

Doc : http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thanks! I combined your answer and coder's. I'd give you both the correct answer if I could.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

[Slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) gives better performance

```
$('button').slice(1).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use one of these:

```
$('button:not(:first)').hide();
$('button:gt(0)').hide();
```