# hide all the a except the first one with jquery

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery - hide all elements except first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462380/jquery-hide-all-elements-except-first-one)

the html code:

```
<div class="productimg"><a href="">test</a><a href="">tow</a><a href="">three</a></div>
<div class="productimg"><a href="">test</a><a href="">hide</a><a href="">show</a></div>
................
```

now, i want to only show the first `a` in each `productimg`when open the page. i using the follow code. but it hide all the image except the first image.

```
$('.productimg a').hide()
$('.productimg a:eq(0)').show();
```

Comment: have you tried using $('.productimg a').not(':first').hide();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tvPQG/2/)**

```
$('.productimg').each(function(){
    $(this).children().not(':first').hide();     
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `gt` to hide all other than first element

```
 $('.productimg').each(function(){
    $(this).find('a:gt(0)').hide();
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ft2mB/1/)

Comment: @roXon this is what he wants "i want to only show the first a in each productimg" but dome is show only one instead of two

Comment: @Adil yes, I need clearly some sleep :)

Comment: No worries, check my answer before you go to sleep :)

Comment: @Adil:now i hopes it meets the author requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.productimg a').each(function(){
   $(this).hide().filter(":first-child").show();
});
```

​

Comment: I missed the productImg div tags,  can you try this now?

Comment: i am sorry, it still can't work. @Adil 's answer is right.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your HTML code is like this,

```
<div id="divID">
    <div class="productimg">
        <a href="">test</a> | <a href="">tow</a> | <a href="">three</a></div>
    <div class="productimg">
        <a href="">test</a> | <a href="">hide</a> | <a href="">show</a></div>
</div>
```

Try this,

```
$("#divID").find("div").each(function () {
            $(this).find('a').hide().eq(0).show();
        });
```

It will work..

(or)

If you want means using CSS, we can achieve this like,

```
.productimg a:not(:first-child)
    {
        display:none;            
    }
```

Comment: yeah,your answer is right. thank you